# iPhone: How to wrap text in drawRect?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How does one draw wrappped text in the `drawRect` method? I'm trying to use atebits' `ABTableViewCell` class to do custom drawing of a table view cell. I'd like to draw a small picture and then text next to it which may or may not need to line wrap. Think of the table cells in a Twitter client like Tweetie which show a profile picture and a tweet. How is that done?

I tried using the various `NSString drawAtPoint` methods, but they don't seem to wrap the text into multiple lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need one of the `drawInRect:withFont:` methods.  They are documented as performing word wrapping.  If you think about it, it makes sense that `drawAtPoint` wouldn't work, because it doesn't know the rectangle the text needs to fit into.

Comment: Thank you, n8gray. It looks like drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:
 does what I'm after. For some reason, a number of the drawAtPoint methods also take forWidth and lineBreakMode arguments which is why I tried those. Actually, some of the drawInRect methods (e.g. drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:) also appear to render text in a single line despite the impression you might get from the name. This threw me off, but I guess I hadn't tried them all. Anyway, you just made my Saturday.

Comment: lineBreakMode also controls truncation (head/tail) so it's appropriate for single-line rendering as well.